# In AspNetCore, what is this currently called and can I encapsulate it?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm currently making a library that interacts with a particular API that requires an oAuth OIDC connection/token and I'd like to make something that makes that particular part easier for users of this library so they don't need all this custom code.

What is this currently called and is there an example of code?

[image: AddOpenIdConnect]

I ask because from trying to get this work, the documentation is ALL OVER THE PLACE. It looks like this particular process has undergone significant changes multiple times as things went on from before netcore to netcore2 and now netcore31.

Comment: extension method? lambda? configuration? I am not sure exactly what part of the code you are referring to...

Comment: I'm looking to add something like `.AddComplicatedOIDC()`. Below what I've shown is a crazy amount of code that I don't want a library consumer to have to put, just want them to set the configuration vars necessary.

Comment: There isn't an official name for this pattern as far as I'm aware. Call it whatever you feel appropriate in your docs.

Comment: What I mean is, what does that code look like? What is it called? Middleware? I can't tell because the terminology is always changing. I don't think it's middleware because that implies something that goes in the pipeline like `app.UseComplicatedOIDC` from my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Both `AddAuthentication` and `AddOpenIdConnect` are [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

An extension method allows you to "add" methods to a type without having to modify the type directly - the methods aren't actually added to the type, but we can call them as if they had been. This is useful in situations where you'd like to extend the behaviour of a class created by a third party but don't have access to the source code.

As for what the particular pattern in question is, whilst there is no canonical name, it's merely a way of encapsulating the configuration of services and dependencies for your application.

`AddAuthentication` is an extension method of `IServiceCollection`, which is `services` type. `AddAuthentication` has a return type of `AuthenticationBuilder`, and `AddOpenIdConnect` is an extension method for `AuthenticationBuilder`. [This](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectExtensions.cs) is the implementation of `AddOpenIdConnect`, but as you're looking to encapsulate the configuration, you could probably do something like this:

```
public static class OpenIdConnectExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder ConfigureOpendIdConnect(
        this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            // Do whatever else you need.
        });
    }
}
```

And call it as follows:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .ConfigureOpendIdConnect()
```

Middleware, on the other hand, is code that executes as part of a pipeline in order to process requests and responses. The middleware sits in the middle of receiving requests and sending responses, hence the name. This allows you do things such as always adding certain headers to responses without that logic being split across your application. As you correctly mentioned, you see these being applied via calls such as `app.UseXyz()`.